# symmetricDS android and server setup

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, symmetricds

I have been trying to setup symmetric server on my laptop and sync sqlite db with mysql database.

The android is same as explained in below example :
http://jumpmind.com/blog/synchronizing-android-applications-part1

and for symmetric server setup i followed following link:
http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html/tutorial.html

My question here is how do i setup the server and what parameter should i pass in external id and node group in android applications . 
Could someone chalk out correct way to setup the server bcoz i tried above tuts for setting up the server but i kept getting error external id value is corp setup parameter is store.

and same for android side too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My application has 2 clients (node111 and node222) configured as follows:

APP1

```
intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_EXTERNAL_ID, "node111");
intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_NODE_GROUP_ID, "clientM");
```

APP2

```
intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_EXTERNAL_ID, "node222");
intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_NODE_GROUP_ID, "clientM");
```

You have to register both nodes on the server as follows:
    symadmin --engine databaseName open-registration clientM node111
and 
    symadmin --engine databaseName open-registration clientM node222

Comment: Hello Pikap, can you please elaborate registration process, Thanks